# What's the use of WearOS "node" parameter in wearAble APIs?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-2.0

In the code below :

`Wearable.getMessageClient(applicationContext).sendMessage(node,label,data)`

What's the point of **node** parameter ? I am able to send & receive data , no matter what value i use for the node.

Answer (score 1):

A node is simply a connected device:

> Multiple wearable devices can be connected to a user’s handheld device. Each connected device in the network is considered a node.

For more details how to detect available nodes, and understand their capabilities, see the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/messages).

Comment: yes.... but , why does the message service still work even if i pass a random string for the Node's value ?